# <div> the container is larger than the specified width and height

Tags: html, css

I have a  container at the top of the page in which some elements are located. These elements have a clear width and height specified in the css file. But if you change the background-color for all the elements, you can see that the containers are larger than the specified parameters. This causes bugs with hovering over the element and subsequent interactions.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #192026;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: white;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.main_container {
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 140px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.top_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.logo {
  width: 164px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 21pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  filter: blur(0.01px);
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.home {
  width: 54px;
  height: 12px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 350px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: #6b7280;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}

.list {
  width: 96px;
  height: 12px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: #6b7280;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: pink;
}

.list:hover,
.home:hover {
  color: #f3f4f6;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<a name="main"></a>
<div class="top_container">
  <div class="logo" onclick="location.href='https://google.com/'">Google</div>
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="list">List</div>
</div>
<div class="main_container"></div>
```

Comment: One solution to this is to use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to include `border-width` and `padding` in the assigned width (rather than the element being sized to the declared `width` and then the `border-width` and `padding` being added on top of that width for (historical) reasons).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing use `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: And check lineheight, its set at 36 and will consume space